# Preheader doesn't display when arriving in Inbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-template, content-builder

I've set up a multiple communication journey which is sending around 10 emails.
For 3 emails out of 10, the preheader is being displayed normally when I receive it in the inbox but for other emails, it doesn't. It just shows the first part of the copy body text.

The preheader is set up in the static box without any dynamic/amp script.
[image]

When sending testing proof the preheader is displayed, but when I populate the journey with recipients it doesn't display anymore.

Did anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before but don't know why it happens.
Inserting the code below into the <head  allows the preheader to display.

```
<!-- START Invisible Preheader -->
<tr>
<td align="center" class="invisible-preheader" style="font-size:0px; width:0px; height:0px; display:none; color:#e8e8e8; line-height:0px;">
<span class="invisible-preheader" style="font-size:0px; width:0px; height:0px; display:none; color:#e8e8e8; line-height:0px;">
%%=AttributeValue("_Preheader")=%%
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- END Invisible Preheader -->
```

Comment: Update for anyone in the same situation as the one explained above.
The root of my issue comes from using the same subject line and the same preheaders for some of the emails. 

Gmail receives the emails under the same chain of communication, thus only the first preheader will be displayed and the rest will be hidden.